# What's with apple pie at the diner?

Tags: analysis, props

I am sure I must have seen this few times were people ask or have apple pie (at a diner), the 2 occurrences that I know for sure is from Men in Black (III) and Sleepy hollow episode 2 season 1 ( But I have a feeling people have been eating apple pie more often than it just being a coincident).

I have a conjecture that maybe some school of writing drums that to it's students as either a signature or technique. So my questions is what is the significance of apple pie being ordered at the diner?

Comment: I think it is not a special film technique, but a cultural topic. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_pie#Apple_pie_in_American_and_Canadian_culture

Comment: @knut : could that be all there is to it? Here in Aus we like apple pie too but haven't seen any aus movie with apple pie in it yet. In the sleepy hollow ep 2, the sheriff's explanation made it sound it is related to transient nature of things, i.e 5 minutes before the hot and crispy and ice cream melt into a one soupy mess.

Comment: I'm from Germany, and for me an apple pie is just a well tasting cake and you eat it normally in the afternoon with a coffee. It's not a dessert after a meal and not an evening meal. There's no special emotion connected to apple pies. But I have the impression the apple pie in the US is a symbol for home and there are special emotions connected to apple pies. It is similar to [Turkeys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkey_(meat)). In Europe it is just a bird you can eat, but I know when I see an American film, that a Turkey meal has special emotions (Thanksgiving...).

Comment: Pie at the diner was usually a way to close the week in Twin Peaks. Given the spooky setting, and the mystery, I'm seeing an homage.

Comment: @wbogacz Hmm, good point. Yet in *Twin Peaks* with its weird play on good old American values like home and family, the apple pie could in turn have served as the classical symbol, too.

Comment: @JoshDM It is a rather general question and not one about *Sleepy Hollow* at all. You haven't tagged it `men-in-black-3` either (and nobody wants to retag it once somebody comes up with another *example*).

Comment: @JoshDM : as Christian Rau Said, It was in Sleepy Hollow that a character explained the significance of Apple Pie in terms on transient nature of life. But the Apple pie has occurred way too often ( except in the Fringe series where it was Rhubarb instead of apple)

Comment: @Arjang - Fringe and Sleepy Hollow have the same showrunner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple pie might be just another dessert in the rest of the world, but in the US it is a cultural icon. It has a long history and tradition dating from the first settlers. It has become a symbol for the warm and familiar. After all, the expression goes "As American as apple pie". So having people eat it in movies is just as American as having them eat burgers.

Comment: Especially at a good old 50s-style diner. ;-)